# Pointing subdomains between hosts

Tags: redirect, subdomain, host

I have recently created a subdomain on one host and pointed it to another (from godaddy to webfaction).  The redirect is working as I can see by the webfaction Site not Configured page opening.  But in the webfaction setup I can't seem to get the site to configure.

So heres a general newbie question.  It says to put the tld in the domains list in the webfaction panel and then you can add subdomains to associate with your apps.  But I was told by a forum user to put the entire subdomain as the domain name, ie mysub.domain.com. But as it doesnt seem to be working, I am in troubleshooting mode.  If I follow the documentation and put the name as 'domain.com' and add a subdomain called 'mysub', then I would be adding the domain there that is hosted on a different server, which seems conflicting.  Could this part of the setup be my problem or should I look elsewhere?

Any tips appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"would be adding the domain there that is hosted on a different server, which seems conflicting. "

On the contrary, this seems the correct thing to do. You need to tell webfactor you're hosting a site with this domain name, whether or not the traffic is actually redirected from godaddy.